# Will soldering jumpwire to DC Booster USB circuit work

Tags: soldering

I wanted solder 2 pins to the positive and negative holes of this usb booster circuit, but I am not sure if it will still work. Please, will the connection work if I do this? Thank you for any help!
[image]

Comment: Soldering won't hurt you once its applied on the board if you take care of any possible short-circuits. What you may need to take care of is the heat of your iron. That heat may damage few of the ICs attached on the board already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. There is nothing special about jumper wire. Solder it using normal soldering techniques.